# When the user cancels the associated account in the action of Google home

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

When the user cancels the associated account in the action of Google home, does it notify our server

Answer (score 0):

User unlinking events trigger a [`DISCONNECT` intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents#unlink).